Use-STSWebIdentityRole returns 'Incorrect Token Audience'
I am trying to get all of my aws accounts through an azure runbook.
I built the oidc provider in aws like I should and linked the right managed identity to the automation account which the runbook is in.
this is my code:
# Import required modules
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module AWS.Tools.Common
Import-Module AWS.Tools.SecurityToken

# Connect to Azure account using Managed Identity

$clientId = "\<clientid\>"
Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId $clientId

# Get the Azure Managed Identity Token

$token1 = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://management.azure.com/").Token

# Define the role ARN and session name

$roleArn = "\<rolearn\>"
$roleSessionName = "SessionName"

# Define additional parameters for the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation

$providerId = "aws.amazon.com"
$durationSeconds = 3600 # Optional: specify the duration for which the credentials are valid (in seconds)

# Assume the role using AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity

$response = Use-STSWebIdentityRole -RoleArn $roleArn -RoleSessionName $roleSessionName -WebIdentityToken $token1 -Duration $durationSeconds`


the error code i get is on the last line and its 'Incorrect Token Audience'
I checked and there is a token being issued so the token being null is not a problem
